# how to migrate custom user field into user registeration email - drupal 7

Tags: email, drupal-7, custom-fields

I have create a custom user field called pm-id. I wish to include this in to the user registration email.

The standard method [user:pm_id] not working

Can anyone help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try either `[user:field_pm_id]` or `[user:field_pm-id]`.  I'm not sure what the machine name for your field is and it's definitely not just `pm-id`.

If you install the [Token module](http://drupal.org/project/token), you should be able to see what tokens are available to you.